# PhpmyAdmin is not working

Tags: xampp

MySQL said: Documentation

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
 Connection for the control user as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username, and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Comment: Rather than use XAMPP, you may want to use a *proper* Apache, MySQL, and PHP installation. There will be far fewer problems going forward, and the skills you learn with the proper Linux packages can be useful if you seek a career in system administration. That said, if you *must* use XAMPP, you'll want to provide a lot more detail than this. For example: (0) which version of Ubuntu are you using (1) what is your phpMyAdmin configuration? (2) Is the issue only with phpMyAdmin, or with other sites on the same server? (3) is there any other information that might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you install XAMPP on ubuntu, this is one type of issue where PHPMyAdmin doesn't work or apache stops. Even I faced the same problem, there was a simple hack for me.
I stopped MySQL running at the backend by:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then I restarted the XAMPP by using the:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

And PHPMyAdmin started working fine.

And for apache I did the same, I stopped the service by using the:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

and restarted the service of XAMPP, it worked too.